# Shopify: How to show geolocation based taxrate on product pages?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, shopify, liquid

I am trying to figure out how to manipulate the javascript and liquid code to show the tax included pricing of the shop articles. The shop is based on the Debut Theme.
I already managed to extract the geolocation of the visitor and store it taxIndex:

```
$.get("https://ipinfo.io/json", function (response) {

        let currentCountry = response.country;
        var taxIndex;
        switch (currentCountry){
          case 'DE':
            taxIndex = 1.19
            break;
          case 'IT':
           taxIndex = 1.22
            break;
          case 'CH':
           taxIndex = 1.077
            break;
          case 'AT':
           taxIndex = 1.2
            break;
        }
        console.log(taxIndex); 

},"jsonp");
```

However, as soon as I try to use the variable to calculate the tax included prices.. it changes the price to 0€.
This method updates the price:

```
_updatePrice: function(evt) {
      var variant = evt.detail.variant;
      var regularPrices = this.priceContainer.querySelectorAll(
        this.selectors.regularPrice
      );
      var salePrice = this.priceContainer.querySelector(
        this.selectors.salePrice
      );
      var unitPrice = this.priceContainer.querySelector(
        this.selectors.unitPrice
      );
      
      var formatRegularPrice = function(regularPriceElement, price) {
        regularPriceElement.innerHTML = theme.Currency.formatMoney(
          price, //Here i think the price has to be multiplied by the taxrate
          theme.moneyFormat
        );
      };
```

I tried inserting the variable in the method mentioned earlier. The output was 0€. However the calculation with a single float not stored in any variable worked perfectly fine.